# How to show numeric touch screen keyboard in windows application WCF

Tags: c#, winforms, wcf

I have a project on the windows application with windows 10. I have search criteria in which I need only a numeric keyboard.

In a touch environment by default, windows are opening, with a full on-screen keyboard instead of numeric only.

Comment: How does your question relate to WCF?

Comment: In Windows applications, there are 2 types of development, WCF and WPF. 
My project is in WCF

Comment: [WCF](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/whats-wcf) is about networking, not about UI

Comment: Windows Communication Foundation is a part of the .NET Framework that provides a unified programming model for rapidly building service-oriented applications.

Comment: It's 100% relevant because UI is WCF-based.

Comment: Perhaps you confused it with WPF?